# Has deploying through ".dodeploy" files gone away in Wildfly 11?

Tags: web-applications, deployment, jboss, wildfly, webdeploy

I just installed Wildfly 11.0.0.Final (Java EE7 Full & Web Distribution) with Java 8 on Amazon Linux.  My Java and Linux versions are below ...

```
[myuser@mydomain ~]$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
[myuser@mydomain ~]$ uname -a
Linux mydomain.mycoonline.org 4.9.43-17.38.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 17 00:20:39 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Has deploying through the creation fo a ".dodeploy" file gone away in Wildfly 11?  I created a blank file named "myproject.war.dodeploy" in my deployments directory, but nothing is happening (e.g. the app is not being deployed).  Below are the perms ...

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ ls -al /usr/java/jboss/standalone/deployments
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  3 deploy evotext 4096 Nov 28 20:05 .
drwxrwxr-x  8 jboss  jboss   4096 Nov 28 19:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x 11 jboss  jboss   4096 Nov 28 19:59 myproject.war
-rw-r--r--  1 jboss  jboss      0 Nov 28 20:12 myproject.war.dodeploy
-rwxrwxr-x  1 deploy evotext 8888 Nov 28 19:24 README.txt
```

The README says I should do it like this but maybe the documentation is old.  What else do I need to do to deploy my application?  The logs reveal nothing.  Note that I'm deploying my app as an exploded war.

**Edit:** Here's the subsystem configuration per jboss-cli.sh ...

```
[myuser@mymachine bin]$ ./jboss-cli.sh
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=deployment-scanner:read-resource(recursive=true)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {"scanner" => {"default" => {
        "auto-deploy-exploded" => true,
        "auto-deploy-xml" => true,
        "auto-deploy-zipped" => true,
        "deployment-timeout" => 600,
        "path" => "deployments",
        "relative-to" => "jboss.server.base.dir",
        "runtime-failure-causes-rollback" => expression "${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}",
        "scan-enabled" => true,
        "scan-interval" => 5000
    }}}
}
```

Comment: Marker files are still present in WF11. Try to check your configuration of `deployment-scanner` subsystem. You can use `jboss-cli` command `/subsystem=deployment-scanner:read-resource(recursive=true)`

Comment: I was deploying as an exploded war and noticed the subsystem by default is not configured to auto-deploy.  So I changed it (included config in question) but still nothign auto-deploys upon creating the ".dodeploy" file.

Comment: If it is `auto-deploy-exploded` set (`true`) your exploded war should ebe deployed automatically and `.deployed` file marker should have been created.

Comment: If it is set to `false`, then you should at least see message by `DeploymentScanner` in you log, with little advice.

Comment: Could it be a a lPOSIX file permission issue ? I see that the deployments forlder doesn't have the same rights as the war and marker file